# Adding an abstract subclass in PHP without modifying all the inheriting children classes

Tags: php, inheritance, design-patterns

I have a similar class hierarchy

```
interface ISomething
{
    public function foo();
    ...
}

abstract class TopAbstract implements ISomething
{
    ...
}

abstract class HighAbstract extends TopAbstract 
{
    public function foo()
    {
        ...
    }
}

and 46(!) classes that inherit from HighAbstract 

class One extends HighAbstract
{
}

...

class FortySix extends HighAbstract
{
}
```

Now I have to add functionnality and that requires having an alternate HighAbstract::foo() (amongst other things).
What would be the best way to achieve that?

- I could just modify HighAbstract but I'd like to keep that new functionality separate (separation of concern)
- I could add a subclass to HighAbstract but then I would have to edit the 46 subclasses to change their parent.
- I could add a trait to HighAbstract but that still implies modifying it (HighAbstract) with branching and using the trait in HighAbstract::foo()
- Any other ideas?

I think using the trait with minimal edits in HighAbstract may be the least bad solution, that way the code is somewhat separated and if the new functionality is ever dropped, it could be done with minimal changes.

What do you think?

Thanks

Comment: so basically you wish for another `HighAbstract:foo()` that works on? what..? a bit unclear.. anyway, as far as i know, traits will be overriden by implementing class.. so it perhaps out of question.

Comment: As of now, none of the 46 child classes define their own foo(), they all use the one in HighAbstract. I don't foresee that changing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem reflects exactly the pitfall of Inheritance which is the most strongly-coupled relationship. You see, when your 46 sub-classes inherit the `HighAbstract` class, they will use the **fixed** and **concrete** implementation of the `foo` method implemented in `HighAbstract` class. No way to alter this at run-time and your only option is modifying source code: either change 46 sub-classes to inherit another parent, or change the source code of the current parent.

Regarding the solutions, I suggest two possible ones:

1) If you are using a good IDE, then you could use the Refactoring feature so you don't need to manually change the parent of your 46 sub-classes.

2) If you anticipate that this kind of change is likely to be happened in the future, then you have to accept modifying source code of your 46 sub-classes, but only one-time, by preferring Aggregation over Inheritance, like this:

```
class FlexibleAbstract extends TopAbstract {

    private $origin;

    public function __construct($origin) {
        $this->origin = $origin;
    }

    public function foo() {
        $this->origin->foo();
    }

}

class One extends FlexibleAbstract {
    ...
}

function somewhere() {
    $oneA = new One(new HighAbstract());
    $oneB = new One(new AlternativeHighAbstract());
    $oneC = new One(new AnotherAlternativeHighAbstract());
}
```

Of course, this solution comes with a little annoyance: every time you create an `One` object you have to create a `TopAbstract` object also. If you hate this you may need to consider the Factory pattern.